# CasperJS evaluate function not working second time

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have minimal knowledge in casperjs & JavaScript, and have been trying to test our new website. After going through casperjs documentation and working out some sample programs I got some understanding about the evaluate() function. But now I am stuck in a weird issue. I have used evaluate function to find all the links inside a web page. Now I am trying to go to all these links and get some info out of them. Now my problem is that the second time I use the evaluate() function it just get skipped. This is totally unexpected behaviour. Please fill in what I am missing. I have attached this sample code I used to reproduce the issue.

```
var BASE_URL = "http://www.google.com";
var links = [];
var divs = [];
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true,});

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

function getDivs(){
        __util__.echo("get Divs Function");
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(divs, function(e) {
        return e;
    });
}

casper.start(BASE_URL, function() {
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    this.echo("links == " + links);
});

casper.waitForUrl(BASE_URL, function(){
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
}, function(){}, 20000);

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("------------------")
    divs = this.evaluate(getDivs);
    this.echo("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
    this.echo("divs == " + divs);
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works.  You are missing an 's' on function getDivs `__utils__`.

```
var BASE_URL = "http://www.google.com";
var links = [];
var divs = [];
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true,});

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

function getDivs(){
    __utils__.echo("get Divs Function");
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    return Array.prototype.map.call(divs, function(e) {
        return e;
    });
}

casper.start(BASE_URL, function() {
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    this.echo("links == " + links);
});

casper.waitForUrl(BASE_URL, function(){
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
}, function(){}, 20000);

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("------------------");
    divs = this.evaluate(getDivs);
    this.echo("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(divs));
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: It'll be interesting if that does fix it, as those semi-colons are optional ones. See http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript  (But, personally, I'd always put them in!)  (BTW, I didn't see any *mis-matched* double/single quotes - is that what you meant?)

Comment: @DarrenCook, you are correct.  My apologies.  I edited my answer with working solution.